# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un valor de atributo de un XML usando Node js?

Tags: nodejs, xml

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto usando Node js en el que tengo que acceder a la API de Musicbrainz y obtener algunos datos.

El caso es que estoy tratando de obtener un valor de la API llamándola a través de una URL, luego obtengo la versión XML de la página resultante y finalmente obtengo el valor que quiero (que es "count") usando el paquete XMLDOM para node js ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom).

El XML se ve así y quiero obtener el valor count (subrayado en rojo):[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función que estoy usando para hacer esto es la siguiente:

```
// Loading of necessary modules and creation of a new application.
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser;

// URL of the musicbrainz API.
var root_url = "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/";

// Example: MBID = 0da580f2-6768-498f-af9d-2becaddf15e0
function getReleases(MBID){

    var releases_URL = root_url + "release-group/" + MBID + "?inc=releases"
    var count
    request({
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'my-musicbrainz-client',
        },
        url: releases_URL,
        json: false
    }, async function (error, response, body) {
    
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(body);
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("release-list")
            console.log("Release list = "+ x)

            count = x.getAttribute('count')  
            console.log("COUNT:"+ y)                                                                  
            return count
        }else{
            console.log("ERROR IN FUNCTION")
        }
    })

}
```

Pero el problema es que count = x.getAttribute ('count') no funciona ya que arroja el error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: x.getAttribute is not a function. ¿Cómo es esto posible si instalé el paquete XMLDOM y según la documentación existe la función getAttribute? ¿Lo estoy usando mal? ¿Hay otra forma de obtener el valor de "count"?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es uno bastante común, y normalmente se debe a la confusión que puede llegar a generar el uso de los métodos propios del objeto Document.

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) devuelve en realidad una lista de elementos (una [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), que no es un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), pero al igual que uno, se puede iterar sobre sus elementos y acceder a los mismos mediante un índice numérico).

Mucha de la confusión viene del uso mucho más frecuente del método [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) que devuelve efectivamente **UN** elemento y no una lista de elementos.

Hay una diferencia muy sutil en el nombre de ambos métodos, y no me refiero a `ByTagName` o `ById` (que es evidente), sino que el primero comienza con `getElements` (plural) y el segundo con `getElement` (singular).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, pero debes aplicarla de acuerdo a tu caso de uso, ya que si tu documento XML (o HTML) contiene más de un *tag* (elemento) llamado `release-list`, entonces la lista devuelta también contendrá más de un elemento, de hecho tendrá tantos elementos como *tags* `release-list` existan en el documento.

Si asumimos que sólo habrá un elemento con dicho nombre, entonces debes escribir el código de la siguiente forma:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("release-list")[0]  // <- indico el primer elemento
```

en donde he especificado que la variable `x` se refiere al primer (y único) elemento de la lista. Con esto, al aplicar el método [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), el mismo efectivamente será parte de la variable `x` ya que la misma es un elemento HTML.

Tal como tú lo tienes, estás tratando de aplicar el método `getAttribute()` sobre un objeto `HTMLCollection`, y como te habrás percatado de la documentación que enlacé anteriormente, este objeto no posee ningún método llamado `getAttribute()`, de allí el mensaje de error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: x.getAttribute is not a function`

Ahora, si tu documento XML/HTML tiene más de un *tag* llamado `release-list`, debes entonces decidir con cual de ellos vas a trabajar, y acceder al mismo siempre mediante un valor índice, tal como en el código anterior.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código muestra el caso para las dos situaciones anteriormente planteadas, tendremos 1 elemento llamado `release-list` y más de un elemento que llamaremos `deploy-list`:

```js
let x = document.getElementsByTagName('release-list')[0];
//obtengo el valor de count y lo convierto en número entero
let count = parseInt(x.getAttribute('count'));
console.log('Release List count:', count);

let lista = document.getElementsByTagName('deploy-list');
// obtenemos el primer elemento de la lista
let y = lista[0]
let countY = parseInt(y.getAttribute('count'));
console.log(y.innerText + ' count:', countY);

// tambien podemos recorrer
// la lista para acceder a sus elementos
for(let indice = 0; indice < lista.length; ++indice) {
  let count = parseInt(lista[indice].getAttribute('count'));
  console.log(lista[indice].innerText + ' count:', count);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<release-list count="42">Release List</release-list>
<deploy-list count="12">Deploy List 0</deploy-list>
<deploy-list count="14">Deploy List 1</deploy-list>
<deploy-list count="24">Deploy List 2</deploy-list>
<deploy-list count="28">Deploy List 3</deploy-list>
```

Se puede dar el caso que tu documento no contenga ningún *tag* con ese nombre, para saber esto puedes verificar el tamaño de la lista devuelta, usando la [propiedad `length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/length):

```js
let numElements = document.getElementsByTagName('release-list').length;
if(numElements > 0) {
  // código para trabajar con los elementos de la lista
}
else {
  // código en caso de que no existan tags llamados 'release-list' en el documento
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y te deje un poco más clara la diferencia entre los métodos mencionados al inicio de mi respuesta.